# ElasticSearch Tire: How to bulk remove?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

Is there a way to bulk remove documents from a ES index with Tire gem?

There is a way to bulk import, but what about remove?

Bulk Import Example:

```
articles = Article.where("id < 10")


Tire.index 'articles' do 
     import articles
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to remove. But, that should be done based on some criteria.

```
id_array = [array of ids to be removed]
query = Tire.search do |search|
        search.query { |q| q.terms :_id, id_array }
      end

index = Tire.index(index_alias)

Tire::Configuration.client.delete "#{index.url}/_query?source=#{Tire::Utils.escape(query.to_hash[:query].to_json)}"
```

Reference: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/309

This actually uses the delete by query api of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

There's a cleaner way:

```
Article.index.bulk :delete, documents, refresh: true
```

`documents` is an array of JSON's. To perform a bulk delete in Elasticsearch, it is enough for it to contain only `_index`, `_type` and `_id` fields. In our case `_index` will be inferred from model name, so we just need to pass the other two.

To sum up:

```
documents = articles_to_delete.map { |a| { _type: 'article', _id: a.id } }
Article.index.bulk :delete, documents, refresh: true
```